# html5media library doesn't work on FF 3.6.3

Tags: firefox, html, html5-video

Am I the only one experiencing this issue? I'm using the [html5media library](http://github.com/etianen/html5media) and the [test page](http://etianen.github.com/html5media/) they provide no longer plays in Firefox 3.6.3, though it plays on the latest Safari, Chrome, Opera, and IE. On FF 3.6.3, it shows the video and the audio with large X through them. I'm using this library on my site and noticed the issue as well. I'm not seeing any errors in the error console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the answer [here](http://devharbor.blogspot.com/2010/06/ogv-and-html5-player-in-firefox.html).

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the ogv version of the video (the version Firefox uses) is not encoded correctly (or at least not in a way that Firefox recognizes), so when Firefox goes to play it, it fails. It works in other browsers because they make use of the mp4 format, which is encoded correctly. Other html5 video plays in my install of Firefox 3.6.3 so I don't believe it is a bug in Firefox. What are you using to encode the ogv format of the video on your site?

Comment: Hi, Ben. Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to use Handbrake ver. 0.9.4 on Windows and choosing the MKV format for the video, then changing the file extension to OGV. When I double-click it, it opens on my machine.

What program do you recommend for converting FLV or MP4 files to OGV? What settings? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the changing of the file extension is probably messing with Firefox. I would suggest using the program Mediacoder, its Open Source and can convert from and to just about anything. Using it is a bit complicated, but near the bottom you can choose the video and audio formats you want to convert to, if you select OGV for the video and OGG for the audio it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. Let me give that a try and see what it does.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, for your help. I found the solution and posted it here: http://devharbor.blogspot.com/2010/06/ogv-and-html5-player-in-firefox.html

It is non-trivial, to say the least, and took quite a bit of digging. There are multiple issues going on all at once.